# Ansible use to_datetime filter and produce time in UTC

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to set a var which will be a seconds since epoch representation of this string, in UTC.

```
start_time: "2021-06-24 22:00:00"
```

I cannot get this to produce anything but the control system's view of the time, meaning the controls system's timezone and not UTC.

```
- set_fact:
    start_time: "{{ ( start_time  | to_datetime).strftime('%s') }}"
```

The above only yields seconds since epoch according to EST.

Is there anything I can pass to the above filter, so it will output the time in UTC ?

I've tried using ways mentioned in [python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime) but seemingly, not everything there applies to what I can use in ansible's `to_datetime`.

Thank you.

Comment: `to_datetime` returns a Python [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) object, and you can use all of the methods in that class. It has nothing to do with Python's `time` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As best I can tell, you'll want to use the *(regrettably undocumented)* [`format=` kwarg](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.10.5/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L97) to that filter to ask it to interpret the string in `+0000` offset, implicitly setting the tz for the resulting `datetime` object

```yaml
- set_fact:
    start_time: '2020-12-31 23:59:59'
- debug:
    msg: epoch localtime is {{ (start_time | to_datetime).timestamp() }}
- debug:
    msg: epoch UTC is {{
      ((start_time ~ "+0000") | to_datetime(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")).timestamp() }}
```

yielding:

```
    "msg": "epoch localtime is 1609487999.0"
    "msg": "epoch UTC is 1609459199.0"
```

which when fed into `gdate` for comparison, seems to behave sanely:

```
$ gdate --date @1609487999.0
Thu Dec 31 23:59:59 PST 2020
$ gdate -u --date @1609459199.0
Thu Dec 31 23:59:59 UTC 2020
```

Comment: the above yields: ```fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got '.'. String: epoch UTC is {{ (start_time ~ \"+0000\") | to_datetime(format=\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z\").timestamp() }}"}```  the first statement works fine, the second - does not. I needed to add quotes of course, but I believe I've added them correctly.

Comment: The example code was missing an extra set of parentheses. I've updated the answer and confirmed that it runs without error.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry about that - I had more debugging text in my local file and was trying to clean it up in the textarea before submitting

Comment: This worked, and beautifully so. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a great way to it using just a playbook, but it's relatively easy to write a custom filter. E.g., if I drop the following code into `filter_plugins/timefilters.py` (where the `filter_plugins` directory is adjacent to my playbook)...

```
import datetime


def filter_to_utc(v, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'):
    t_local = datetime.datetime.strptime(v, format).astimezone()
    offset = t_local.utcoffset()
    t_utc = (t_local - offset).replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
    return t_utc


class FilterModule:
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'to_utc': filter_to_utc,
        }
```

...then I can write the following playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    start_time: "2021-06-24 22:00:00"
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        start_time_utc: "{{ start_time | to_utc }}"

    - debug:
        msg: '{{ start_time }} -> {{ start_time_utc }}'
```

And get this output:

```
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "2021-06-24 22:00:00 -> 2021-06-25 02:00:00+00:00"
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**Update** I think I like @mdaniel's solution better. It's still good to remember that if you have complex logic it's very simple to just drop it into a custom filter plugin.

Comment: @mdanile's looks great but I'm having time implementing it. I will try yours as well thank you. Where should the `filter_plugins` live within a role structure ? the root dir of the role ?

Comment: The `filter_plugins` directory should be adjacent to ("in the same directory as") your playbook, or you could place it inside a role directory if it is role-specific.